# Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword always skips to else

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make a login and signup page using Firebase on android, and I can register users but not login, I can see the registered users in the database. The login method always goes to the else part. Here is the code

```
    mLogin_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = mLoginEmail.getEditText().toString();
            String password = mLoginPassword.getEditText().toString();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                mLoginProgress.setTitle("Loggin In");
                mLoginProgress.setMessage("Please Wait!");
                mLoginProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                mLoginProgress.show();

                loginUser(email, password);
            }
        }
    });

}


private void loginUser(String email, String password) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                mLoginProgress.dismiss();

                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                        finish();

                    } else{
                mLoginProgress.hide();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "nope, skipping to else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                }
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 else{
     mLoginProgress.hide();
    Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Replace your toast with the toast above to be able to know why it is going to the else statement.

Change this:

```
  String email = mLoginEmail.getEditText().toString();
  String password = mLoginPassword.getEditText().toString();
```

to this:

```
  String email = mLoginEmail.getText().toString();
  String password = mLoginPassword.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Actually I had to change it to 

      String email = mLoginEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
      String password =mLoginPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();

But yeah, that did it. Thank you!!